# React: How can I pass a value to my main App() function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-component

I have a react app and I want to pass a value (the "groupId") to the main app component.

My app component is defined as `function App()`. I tried to pass the parameter value using the following way:

**index.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './scss/index.scss';
import App from './App';

const targetDivName= 'myapp-ui';
const targetDiv = document.getElementById(targetDivName);
const groupId: string = targetDiv?.getAttribute("data-group-id") ?? '';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App groupId={ groupId } />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  targetDiv
);
```

**App.tsx:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Box } from "./components/Box";
import styles from './scss/App.module.scss';

function App(groupId: string) {
    return (
        <div className={ styles.orchestratorUi }>
          <Box groupId={ groupId } />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

But this yields the following error (compile and run):

```
Type '{ groupId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

How can I pass a value from the HTML code through my App() into the main component (`Box` in this example).

Comment: Remember that `props` is passed as an object, not individual parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```js
function App(groupId: string) {
```

to

```js
function App({groupId}: any) {
```

or even better to

```js
interface Props {
  groupId: string
}

function App({ groupId }: Props) {
```

What happens with your code is that typescript interprets `groupId` in `function App(groupId: string) {` to be of type `string`, and instead receives an object when you instanciate `App`.

In your case, this object is `{"groupId": groupId}` where `groupId` here is the variable you assigned in `App.tsx`.

Comment: Thanks, got it working by following your example (and partially that of others).

Answer (score 4):

Props are passed as an *object*, so change

```
function App(groupId: string) {
```

to

```
//                    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv−−−−−− declaring the type of props
function App({groupId}: {groupId: string}) {
//           ^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− using destructuring
```

That declares the first parameter for `App` to be of type `{groupId: string}`, and grabs `groupId` from props using destructuring.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the destructuring concept.

Answer (score 1):

That's because React components accept props as objects.

First of all, it is necessary to get `groupId` from props object like this:

```js
function App({ groupId }) {
```

[Here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b26786eade45d9487e62b708afe5a88771cd4d3a/types/babel-plugin-react-html-attrs/index.d.ts#L556-L562) you can find types for function components.

So the correct way to define props, that the `App` component accepts, would be:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Box } from "./components/Box";
import styles from './scss/App.module.scss';

interface AppProps {
  groupId: string;
}

// React.FC is an alias for React.FunctionComponent
// https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/v16/index.d.ts#L544
const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ groupId }) => {
  return (
    <div className={ styles.orchestratorUi }>
      <Box groupId={ groupId } />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your index is fine, your main component should be like:
function App(props) {
.
.

.
.